# how do you get the position of the VR headset in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to figure out how to get the position of the VR headset in three.js, I have made a scene and have live controller positions, but how do I access the position of the headset so I know where the users head is?

Answer (score 2):

Just extract the world position from the camera's world matrix like so:

```
const position = new THREE.Vector3();
position.setFromMatrixPosition( camera.matrixWorld );
```

Comment: that looks like it sets a position, not queries a position. Can you clarify?

Comment: The transformation of the headset is copied to the camera of your scene. The above code just extracts it from the respective world matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused, and the docs are really vague. How would I then finally get the x,y,z co-ordinates?

Comment: `position` is of type `Vector3`. That means you can access the vector coordinates like so: `position.x`, `position.y` `position.z`.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it, thank you to Mugen87 for pointing me in the right direction!

> const v = new THREE.Vector3( ); v.setFromMatrixPosition(
> camera.matrixWorld );
>
> console.log("x pos="+v.x); console.log("y pos="+v.y); console.log("z
> pos="+v.z);

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer, you should accept the existing one. What you do is not how stackoverflow works.